# Google DFP image ad 300x250 is not rendering properly in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, google-dfp

I'm trying to show custom ad size 300x250

```
self.bannerView = [[DFPBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(300, 250)) origin:self.view.center];
[self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"my_ad_id";
self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
self.bannerView.delegate = self;
[self.bannerView loadRequest:request];
self.bannerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; //setting background color for testing
```

ad recived but not displayed properly, using latest sdk GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-6.9.2. Ad image shows right side of the banner instead of showing full size. DFP creative type is Image, uploaded image size is 300x250(1x) and 600x500(2x)

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Still haven't found a solution.

Comment: It works now, I did not change anything, it works now. May be DFP side issue.